# Specific loading of related manytomany field in queryset

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm using intermediate model with extra fields on many-to-many relationships like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    a = models.ManyToManyField(A, through='AB')

class AB(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

By default, `AB.date` is NULL in database.

I retrieve all my `B` instances with something like this `B.objects.all()`.

Then, for each instance of `B`, I can get a set of `AB` like this, `b_instance.ab_set.all()`.

How to load only `ab_set` elements where `date` is null ?

In SQL it would have looked like this :

```
SELECT * FROM B
INNER JOIN AB ON AB.id = B.ab_id AND AB.date IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a filter with a [**`__isnull`** [doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) *field lookup* for that, like:

```
b_instance.ab_set.filter(date__isnull=True)
```

So we `.filter(..)` on the set, by specifying that the `date` field `isnull`.

Alternatively, if you for example want to query with a non-`None` `date` as well, you can filter with `date=None`:

```
b_instance.ab_set.filter(date=None)
```

Comment: I saw about the `__isnull` _field lookup_ . In my example, I want to automatically apply filter on `B` when I use `B.objects.all()`. Something like this doesn't work : `B.objects.filter(ab__date__isnull=True)`.

Comment: But `B.objects.filter(..)` returns a list of `B` objects (some items occur multiply times) *per* `ab` relation that has a `NULL`-date. So if a `B` element has three `ab` related instances, and two are `NULL`s, then that item will occur twice in the queryset. In case an object has *no* `ab`s, or for example one non-`NULL`, then it will not be in the queryset.

Comment: @super_sk: do you want `B` instances that have *at least* one `NULL` date, or *only* `NULL`-dates? What for `B`s that have no `AB` instance?

Comment: I want all `B` instances whatever the number of `ab` they have. However, no `ab` with `NON-NULL` date must appear in the set of each `B` retrieved. Sorry, It seems to be unclear :( .

Comment: For instance, `[b1, b2]` and `b1.ab_set = [b1ab1 (null date), b1ab2 (date)]` and `b2.ab_set = [b2ab1 (date), b2ab2 (date)]`. The expected result is `b1` and `b2` with respectively `b1ab1` and `empty_set`.

Comment: Well as far as I know, you can not dynamically set the values of a `RelatedManager`, this would probably also conflict with SOLID design principles.

Comment: so the only way for me to perform my fetch is by implementing custom SQL request ?

Comment: @super_sk: no, the answer should obtain `b1.ab_set.filter(date=None) == [b1ab1]` and `b2.ab_set.filter(date=None) == []`. What I mean is that you can not pass a queryset of `b`s where you "manipulated" the relatedmanagers like `ab_set` specifically for that queryset.

Comment: Thanks you for your answers. It doesn't solve my problem anyway because Django's ORM cannot perform something like `select * from B b inner join AB ab ON b.id = ab.b_id AND ab.date IS NULL`. Or maybe it's possible but I don't master Django enough to do this.

Answer (score 0):

With some researches about my problem, I finally found something that could answer the problem.

I used `Model method` to filter my set of objects :

```
class B(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_ab_with_null_date(self):
        return self.ab_set.filter(date__isnull=True)
```

So, I can get filtered `ab_set` in my template like this :

```
{% for b in list_of_B %}
    {% for ab in b.get_ab_with_null_date %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

> Do you think there is a more efficient way to perform this ?

Also, I saw something about overriding [Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers)
like this :

```
b = B.objects.get(...)
b.custom_manager.get_ab_with_null_date() # return filtered ab_set with null date
```

Since I'm not manipulating my `ab_set` directly in the view, I think it's not so useful for my case.